# Eclipse IDE not responding/hangs for long times

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-2018-09

I have a problem with the Eclipse 2018-09 JEE version causes the IDE to be unresponsive for longer time. Sometimes it doesn't recover at all.
I even created a new workspace but it doesn't take long before the same problem occurs.
It is getting very frustrating.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

There are MANY instances of both the Interrupted and the Timeout exception in the log:

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2019-05-24 08:38:52.455
    !MESSAGE 
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:347)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSBasedHover.getHoverInfo(LSBasedHover.java:108)
        at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo2(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 4 0 2019-05-24 08:39:54.416
    !MESSAGE 
    !STACK 0
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1771)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.declaration.OpenDeclarationHyperlinkDetector.detectHyperlinks(OpenDeclarationHyperlinkDetector.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HyperlinkDetectorRegistry$HyperlinkDetectorDelegate.detectHyperlinks(HyperlinkDetectorRegistry.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:289)
```

Comment: As far as I know, that's a bug that has been fixed some time ago. Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades). You are two releases behind.

Comment: This looks related to the version of the Spring Tools you have installed. Also update those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

today i have same issue.

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Language servers. Disable all checkboxes, apply & close. Restart IDE. It solved problem for me.

below link might help you
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/25